# Disable Weekends on HTML 5 input type date

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to disable all weekends for HTML 5 input type date?

```
<input id="date1" size="60" type="date" format="MM/DD/YYYY" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" />
```

Comment: As I understand from the reference, I would say no. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) you can only set min/max dates.

Comment: @DanielAWhite: That doesn't really look like a duplicate (min/max dates versus weekends.)  Especially because that question had the answer of "by the standards, yes, but practically, no, not yet."  And this one is just a "no."

Comment: This is not ***exactly*** a dupe. The answers in the other post only address min/max dates, which doesn't answer the OP. I just wrote there an answer that address also the weekend dates, but it has (as of now) less that three votes. TL;DR no answer in the dupe target answer the OP with a sufficient amount of votes. I don't know what to make of it, I'll skip the reopen vote review :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for HTML 5 input type date this isn't possible.
You can use `flatpickr` as an alternative: ( https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/examples/#disabling-specific-dates )
It looks better and also can do what you are asking for!
In the documentation is mentioned a property named `disable` that you can use to remove weekends.

```
{
"disable": [
    function(date) {
        return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
    }
],
"locale": {
    "firstDayOfWeek": 1 // start week on Monday
}
```

}

**Full working example:**

```js
$("#date1").flatpickr({
    enableTime: true,
    dateFormat: "m-d-Y",
    "disable": [
        function(date) {
           return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);  // disable weekends
        }
    ],
    "locale": {
        "firstDayOfWeek": 1 // set start day of week to Monday
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Using Flatpickr</title>
  <!--  Flatpicker Styles  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/flatpickr.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/themes/dark.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <input id="date1"  placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" data-input />
        <!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!--  Flatpickr  -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/flatpickr.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 23):

Just check the day. If it's a weekend you can reset the value and tell the user to pick something else.

```js
const picker = document.getElementById('date1');
picker.addEventListener('input', function(e){
  var day = new Date(this.value).getUTCDay();
  if([6,0].includes(day)){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.value = '';
    alert('Weekends not allowed');
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="date1" size="60" type="date" format="MM/DD/YYYY" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" />
```

Comment: Note some browser like Chrome will set the date when you use the arrows or select another month. That screws this up if it happens to be on a weekend, because instead of going to the next month you just get the error and it resets.

Answer (score 2):

> some browser like Chrome will set the date when you use the arrows or select another month

To avoid this problem, I have found that the `setCustomValidity` method was more useful to my use case than resetting the value of the input.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#implementing_a_customized_error_message

Here is an example below. On form submission, if a week-end is selected, the form won't actually submit and the error will be displayed.

```js
const picker = document.getElementById('date1');
picker.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  var day = new Date(this.value).getUTCDay();
  if([6,0].includes(day)){
    e.target.setCustomValidity('week-end not allowed')
  } else {
    e.target.setCustomValidity('')
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="date1" size="60" type="date" format="MM/DD/YYYY" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I got an error using addEventListner, thus I tried it with Jquery

```
<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

$('#date_field').change(function() {
    var date = new Date($(this).val());
    const day = date.getDay();
    if(day==0)
    {
        alert("You can't select sunday");
        $(this).val("");
    } 
});
}); 
</script>
```

You can change days of week from day==0 till day=6 as per your need.