# How to disable previous days from today

Tags: javascript

I would like to request assistance on how I can show a specific dates on my date picker, blocking the weekends and disable the previous days from today.

**Month shown only:** June and July
**Days:** June 1 to July 31
*Disable the weekend*s
*Disable the previous days from today*

```
<input id="date1" type="date" min="2021-06-01" max="2021-07-31" name="APPOINTMENTDATE" data-field-type="Text">

<script>
const picker = document.getElementById('date1');
picker.addEventListener('input', function(e){
  var day = new Date(this.value).getUTCDay();
  if([6,0].includes(day)){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.value = '';
    alert('Weekends not allowed');
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you don't have the option to disable specific dates in native html date picker, whereas `min` and `max` dates are possible. But you can validate and prevent the input, as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56483029

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863189/disable-weekends-on-html-5-input-type-date

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you want *jQuery UI* **datepicker**. Here is how to do this using the plugin. You can use `maxDate` and `minDate` to get your range, and `beforeShowDay` with `datepicker.noWeekends` to disable all weekends. `minDate` set to `0` will disable all days before today.

EDIT: added a better option that will not change with the current time for `maxDate`.

Then set a variable up for date, month and year, get each using a `new Date()` obj:

```
const date = new Date();
const year = date.getFullYear();
const month = date.getMonth();
```

Then you can set your `maxDate` to `new Date(year, month+1, '31')`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    const date = new Date();
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = date.getMonth();
    $("#cal").datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
      maxDate: new Date(year, month + 1, '31'),
      minDate: 0,
    });
  });
})
```

```css
.ui-datepicker {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.ui-datepicker-header {
  background-color: #616eff;
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.ui-datepicker-title {
  color: #1d1d1d;
}

.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default {
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
}

.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default:hover {
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: transform .15s;
}

.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active {
  border: 0;
  background: #616eff;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> Date: <input id="cal" type="text" name="APPOINTMENTDATE" data-field-type="Text">
```

For a native datepicker with HTML 5 you can create an array of months and the use `const date = new Date; const now = date.now()`, then you can format the string to match that which the `min` attribute will take => `yyyy-mm-dd`. Then use JS to place the string into your min attribute.

Then to handle the weekends, use your current code, however, instead of a pesky alert, create a span tag and append it to the parent element and place it next to your input with a warning and styling indicative to a warning. Use a timeout to remove the tooltip once the animation fades.

```js
const months = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12']
const now = new Date()
const formattedDate = now.getFullYear() + '-' + months[now.getMonth()] + '-' + now.getDate()

document.getElementById('date').min = formattedDate

document.getElementById('date').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var day = new Date(this.value).getUTCDay();
  if ([6, 0].includes(day)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.value = '';
    
    const tooltip = document.createElement('SPAN')
    tooltip.classList.add('tooltip')
    tooltip.textContent = "Sorry weekends are not available!"
    e.target.parentNode.append(tooltip)
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.tooltip').remove()
    },3000)
    
  }
})
```

```css
.warning {
  background-color: pink;
  color: darkred;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left: 130px;
  padding: .2rem .5rem;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  animation: fade 3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid darkred;
}

.tooptip::before {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;   
  border-right:10px solid pink; 
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input id="date" type="date" min="" max="2021-07-31" name="APPOINTMENTDATE" data-field-type="Text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the selected date with today's date and show alert in case if it prior to today's date.

```js
const picker = document.getElementById('date1');
picker.addEventListener('input', function(e){
  var day = new Date(this.value).getUTCDay();
  e.preventDefault();
  const selectdDay = new Date(this.value).setHours(0,0,0,0);
  const today = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));
  if(selectdDay < today) {
    this.value = "";
    alert('Previous day is not allowed');
  }
  if([6,0].includes(day)){
    this.value = '';
    alert('Weekends not allowed');
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="date1" type="date" min="2021-06-01" max="2021-07-31" name="APPOINTMENTDATE" data-field-type="Text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you must set `min` attribute to `today Date`.

Try this one for `Disable the previous days from today` :

```
 var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
 document.getElementById("date1").setAttribute('min', today);
```

```js
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementById("date1").setAttribute('min', today);

alert("min Data " + today)
```

```html
    <input id="date1" type="date" min="2021-06-01" max="2021-07-31" name="APPOINTMENTDATE" data-field-type="Text">
```

Answer (score 0):

a built-in function of datepicker for no weekend days selection.

set minDate equals today, so that there is selection before this date allowed.

```
$(".selector").datepicker({ 
   beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
   //set today's Date as minDate,  
   minDate: new Date() 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way u can stop users from selecting yesterday. But didn't see any way to disable the user from selecting those dates with the HTML date picker. But u can use jQuery to achieve this, [here](https://webkul.com/blog/jquery-datepicker/) is a resource showing that.

```
<input id="date1" type="date" min="2021-06-01" max="2021-07-31" name="APPOINTMENTDATE" data-field-type="Text">

<script>
  const picker = document.getElementById('date1');

  picker.addEventListener('input', function(e){

    let errorMessage;

    const day = new Date(this.value).getUTCDay();
    
    if([6,0].includes(day)) {
      errorMessage = 'Weekends not allowed';
    }

    const dateStr = new Date(this.value).toLocaleDateString();
    const yesterdayStr = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - 1000*60*60*24).toLocaleDateString();

    if(dateStr === yesterdayStr) {
      errorMessage = 'Choosing yesterday is not allowed';
    }

    if(errorMessage) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.value = '';
      alert(errorMessage);
    }
  });
```